# Help with difficult telescoping series question: $\frac3{1!+2!+3!}+\frac4{2!+3!+4!}+\ldots+\frac{2012}{2010!+2011!+2012!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

Evaluate

$$\frac3{1!+2!+3!}+\frac4{2!+3!+4!}+\ldots+\frac{2012}{2010!+2011!+2012!}\;.$$

I see that the question is telescoping, but I don't know how to break it down into a form similar to that of the most basic telescoping series.
What would be the best method to simplify this question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The denominator of each term is $$(n-2)!+(n-1)!+n!=(n-2)!(1+n-1+(n-1)n) = (n-2)!\,n^2,$$
so each term simplifies to
$$\frac{n}{(n-2)!n^2}=\frac{1}{(n-2)!n}=\frac{n-1}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!},$$
and now you can see that the series telescopes.

Comment: I see how it telescopes but Im slightly confused to how to get to the answer.

Comment: If the question were to compute $(1/2!-1/3!)+(1/3!-1/4!)+(1/4!-1/5!)$, what would you do with that?

Comment: besides the 1/2! and -1/5!, every other term has a negative and positive counterpart. These numbers would cancel out and I would be left with 1/2! and -1/5!. By then I would preform the compuatation (1/2!-1/5!) which is 59/120

Comment: Okay, then how about $(1/2!-1/3!)+(1/3!-1/4!)+\cdots+(1/2011!-1/2012!)$?

Comment: same story, now we just subtract 1/2012! from 1/2!

Comment: Sounds good to me!